# Can I directly "Extract" an Item from a List<>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a List of 5 items.

I want to extract the last item, like :

```
string lastItem = myList.Last();
```

but after this, myList must contain 4 items, everythings except the last one, which is just extracted.

Is it possible? Or I need to use .Take(4)?

Comment: Hi markzzz, I'm afraid you can do that just in Queue, if you want this in a List you should `Remove` the item yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`List.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx), [`List.RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx) or [`List.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) methods to remove elements from the list.

To remove the last element of the list after you obtained a reference to it using the list indexer you use:

```
var element = myList[myList.Count - 1];
myList.RemoveAt(myList.Count - 1);
```

Using `RemoveAt` instead of `Remove` is more efficient because there is no need to first find the index of the item to be removed and also to note that `Remove` just removes the first occurrence that matches the item to be removed, so in a list with duplicates it will not be the last element.

Finally, if you have an algorithm where will be removing the last item of a list several times, you might as well consider another data structure, like for example a [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

You can do as following if you want to take the last.

```
string lastItem = myList.Last();
myList.Remove(myList.Last());
//myList.Count() will now be 4.
```

Comment: That won't remove the last item if the last item has been added to the list multiple times.

Comment: That's true. If the list can contain multiples of the samte string, this will not work asexpected. Then the RemoveAt(int) is more accurate.

Comment: In the case of an `IList<T>` using `Last` is special-cased to use `Count` so is ok, but in the case of a non-`IList<T>` item it will spawn two enumerators and do two full iterations. That said, the window for this inefficiency is pretty small as it'd likely only happen on custom collections and obviously doesn't apply directly to the OP as they use `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an extension method that takes any index to do the fetch/removal:

```
public static T Extract<T>(this List<T> list, int index)
{
    var item = list[index];
    list.RemoveAt(index);
    return item;
}
```

The last item can always be found using `Count - 1`, so the call is simply:

```
var item = list.Extract(list.Count - 1);
```

It then means you can "extract" any item by index.

Answer (score 2):

Create an extension method to do this

```
public static class Extension
{
  public static string RemoveLast(this IList<string> myList)
  {
     int lastItemIndex = myList.Count - 1;
     string lastItem = myList.Last();
     myList.RemoveAt(lastItemIndex);
     return lastItem; 
  }
}
```

call it as

```
string itemRemoved = lst.RemoveLast(); //this will delete the last element from list & return last element as well
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Stack instead of a List it seems more appropriate

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
    int pop = stack.Pop();
    Assert.AreEqual(stack.Count, 4);
    Assert.AreEqual(pop, 5);
}
```

Comment: Good approach, but it depends on what he is doing with the list. Just for the specific issue described by the owner of the question, you approach seems good